# Is an image display website better suited for procedural or OO programming?

Tags: php

I have a comics website, http://hittingtreeswithsticks.com, and I guess I'm unclear as to which style, procedural or OO, that it's written in.

Basically, there are several "templates", homepage.php, viewall.php, viewFullSize.php, which call upon various scripts... namely, the templates all include imageDisplay.php, which has several scripts which determine how to query based on which category, tag, or subsite is selected.

I've read a lot about the benefits of OO programming- when it's used and when it's not... but am still having trouble answering this question.

The way I understand the difference between OOP and procedural from an example standpoint is:

OOP: If you have a website where a user can create an object, such as a forum where a user can submit a post... then you'd want to go with OOP because you'd want to allow users to create several instances of the Article class.

Procedural: I went with what I think is procedural because my comics website simply displays comics out to users. A user can submit a comment using DISQUS, or like/dislike. I don't see where I'd be able to fit the OOP paradigm into a simple image display site.

**So, the question is:**

To use OOP, do you necessarily need to have several objects that would be instantiated? Or are there other benefits I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do **both**.

Just call the procedures "methods", or your methods "procedures".

Objects don't need to correspond to real world objects, it's as much about modularization and moving code into isolated (!) chunks as about "objects".

All in all, a website is not the best to understand OOP. Too little inheritance happening.

Instead, **write a simulation**. For example, a road with maybe a crossroad and a few drivers driving around.

Start with a stupid driver, then try to allow for *subclassing* it with different smarter drivers. Or aggressive drivers. And see if they can cause more traffic jams.

Try to start with a problem where you have natural objects that *share a lot of traits*, and only differ in a few.

Comment: Okay, but I'm struggling to see how OOP would fit in if I don't have a clear object I need to instantiate... I just have template files that call several script files

Comment: Make objects for tags, pages, comics, comments, ...

Comment: Can you recommend some good tutorials on proper site design? I feel my site is a shapeless collection of random templates and scripts

Comment: You will have to find your own style. Again, try isolation. If something is reusable in a different context, then it's logically an object (even if your syntax might still only consist of procedures). And then try to find shared code in these modules and try to move it to a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Always code OOP. The only reason people ever code procedural PHP is because they're using pre PHP 5.

To answer your question, no. You can have a single object. OOP is just for code organization and the implementation of DRY principals.

Comment: Right, but I guess my question is- I don't see an "object" that needs creation... there are just different templates that call different methods from the imageDisplay.php file.

Comment: Take PHP out of it for a second and introduce a front end MVVM javascript framework like Backbone or Angular. Now you can have all the images or comic pages as objects and set listeners and shared properties among them. The same principals apply on the back end for updating database values through a model.

Comment: Can you recommend some good tutorials on proper site design, as well as the MVVM frameworks? I feel my site is a shapeless collection of random templates and scripts

Comment: Sure http://backbonetutorials.com

Answer (score 0):

OO is normally a better aproach, as long as you document correctly and are aware of class dependencies/herance/hierarquy.

Besides adding a bit of security to your code, an correctly implemented OOP is trully powerfull for adding and upgrading new features, organize code, reuse logic.
As everything is within it's object definition, you always know where and what to look for.

Yes, is kinda tricky at times but it pays.

Non OOP is good practice only in basic methods, small coding.
Something like the "Hello world" :p
Or a non server content dependedence of content or better known as static websites.

For OO you don't require an object to have definition like parametters or whatever.
In your case, you could have an object for db handling, another for top menu bar, another that handle comic book related stuff like sorting, listing...
Basicly wraping everything in it's corresponding place, reusing code more efficiently..

Hope this helped